# Handing out resumes during a seminar/workshop/yearly event?

Tags: resume

I will be attending a bi-annual event as a potential employee (I'm currently a junior in college).  I will be carrying my resume with me to pass out to potential employers if it is requested.  My question is...should I just hand them the resume?  Should I put each resume in an envelope?  If so, should it be in a letter sized envelope or would it be okay to fold it for this occasion?  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this event a job fair? Or are you giving out unsolicited resumes?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume this is a carer/job fair event.

Do not put your resume in a envelope. You are going to be going up and talking with potential employers. When talking with them, you want to refer them to your resume. They will also want to read through it on the spot. Having your resume in an envelope will just slow down the process.

Things I would suggest you do (if you're in North America):

1. Get a LinkedIn account. I know a few companies that will ask to connect to you via that. And honestly, it can't hurt.
2. Print enough resumes.
3. Look at the companies attending, and do some research into the ones you're most interested in. Seek them out first when you get there.

Comment: You probably want a notebook or a folder or something like that and put your stack of resumes in that so you can easily pull one out when asked.

Comment: Why do people still encourage printing out resumes? Use bluetooth or wifi to transfer it to the recruiter's device: http://nrecursions.blogspot.in/2015/10/do-recruiters-still-need-to-ask-for.html